# AngularJS Typeahead prepopulation

Tags: angularjs, typeahead

I have a typeahead that I want to contain a description but store the Id.

I'm currently doing it something like this...

```
            <input type="text"
                ng-model="SelectedWarehouse.Info"
                typeahead="whs.info for whs in warehouses($viewValue)"
                typeahead-on-select="POHeader.warehouseId=$item.id;"
                class="form-control input-sm "
                id="whs" placeholder="Warehouse"
                ng-disabled="isReadOnly"
                typeahead-wait-ms="500"
                ng-enter="say('hello');" />
```

Where the jsonp that I get from the $scope.warehouses function looks something like this:
([{"id":"10", "info": "Lakeland (10)"}, {"id":"11", "info": "Denver (11)"}])
of course along with the appropriate jsonp callback info -- this is just an example

The sloppy part of it is this:
When the screen opens the $scope.SelectedWarehouse is not populated with anything.
I then wrote something to pre-populate the SelectedWarehouse but there has to be a better way to do this using typeahead.

What's the right/good/best (pick one) way to do this?

Another problem is not knowing when my async call will actually populate my objects.  Promises promises...  I thought I'd try using the ng-change function call hoping that when the data gets populated the ng-change function would fire ... so far that didn't work.  I'm not quite done experimenting with that though...

Here's part of my $resource factory.  What would I need to do to get a success call working with this?

```
 ipoModule.factory('SearchRepository', function ($resource) {
    return {
        get: function (txt) {
            return $resource('/api/Search?SearchText=' + txt).query()
        },
        getBuyers: function () {
            return $resource('api/Buyers').query()
        },
        getVendors: function () {
            return $resource('api/Vendors').query()
        },
        getVendorSearch: function (txt) {
            return $resource('api/Vendors/' + txt + "?callback=JSON_CALLBACK").query()
        }, ....
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made my own work-around because I couldn't get the pre-population to work with a typeahead.

```
   <input type="text"
        ng-model="POHeader.SelectedWarehouse"
        typeahead="whs.info for whs in warehouses($viewValue)"
        typeahead-on-select="POHeader.warehouseId=$item.id;"
        class="form-control input-sm "
        id="whs" placeholder="Warehouse"
        ng-disabled="isReadOnly"
        typeahead-wait-ms="500" />
```

I changed the view that populates the POHeader to include a field called SelectedWarehouse.  This is my pre-formatted typeahead value which looks the same as the whs.info returned from the typeahead warehouses list.

It's not ideal but it works and I can't afford to waste more time on this.

Answer (score 0):

i think something like this might work. You can bind the typeahead to a collection instead of a method, and update that collection on keypress by fetching values from the server. You can also watch for changes on the collection so you will know when your data is about to be populated.

See Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/yfz6S/17/

**view.html**

```
<div style="margin: 40px;">
<div ng-controller="WarehousesCtrl">
    <pre>query: {{query | json}}</pre>
    <pre>selectedWarehouse: {{selectedWarehouse | json}}</pre>
    <input
        class="form-control input-sm"
        ng-model="query"
        typeahead="warehouse.info for warehouse in warehouses | filter:$viewValue"
        typeahead-on-select="selectedWarehouse = $item;"
        ng-keypress="fetchWarehouses();"
    />
</div>
</div>
```

**controller.js**

```
.controller('WarehousesCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$q', function ($scope, $http, $q) {
    $scope.query = null;
    $scope.selectedWarehouse = null;
    $scope.warehouses = [];
    $scope.fetchWarehouses = function() {
        $http.jsonp(
            'http:/mysite.com/mywarehouses?q=' + $scope.query
        ).success(function(data){
            $scope.warehouses = data.warehouses;
        }).error(function(){
            // this request will fail so lets just set some dummy warehouses
            $scope.warehouses = [
                {id:1, info:"Toronto"},
                {id:2, info:"Tobermory"},
                {id:3, info:"Oshawa"},
                {id:4, info:"Ottawa"},
                {id:5, info:"Ajax"},
            ];
        });
    };

}]);
```

Comment: The $viewValue is not passing to fetchWarehouses.  When fetchWarehouses is called the value of $viewValue is not populated yet.  That's also the case for ng-model.  If I change ng-keypress="fetchNatures(query)" I get similar results.  query is undefined or a prior value.  (If I type "A" query is undefined, if I type "AB" then query is "A", etc).

Comment: @D.Kermott Did you figure it out already? Was going to create an example on JSFiddle.

Comment: @D.Kermott updated my answer and included a demo link.

Comment: The demo link does not pre-populate the typeahead with data because the variable is initialized to null.

Comment: I have a work-around.  I changed my view to include the display data for the typeahead (in addition to the id field).  This way I can bind to the display data in my model and set the id field.  As this is merely a view the display variable is ignored anyway.